# How to check If email already registered in Swift via PHP?

Tags: php

I have a register form with few details such as name, email and phone number using PHP to store in MySql. The code is working, and I added some code lines in the PHP file to check if the email already taken. The code still working but when ever found the email registered the PHP file will not response to swift to take action after that.

Here is the Swift part:

```
func uploadImage() {
    
    selectedImageImageView.image = selectedImageImageView.image?.resize(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
   // showImageSize()
    
    
    self.showActivityIndicator()
    
    //Post URL
    let url = "https://uae.mywebsite.com/image-upload/upload.php"
    
    //Getting text from textFiled!
    let name = textName.text!
    let email = textEmail.text!
    let phone = textPhoneNumber.text!
    
    
    //Call Parameters
    let params: Parameters = ["name": name,"email": email, "phone": phone]
    
    //Checking image place holder
    let image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageedit_1_8287656945")
    
    //Checking if empty name or age fileds
    if name.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || phone.isEmpty {
        
        self.hideActivityIndicator()
        myAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Make sure you enter all the required information!")
    }
    
    //Checking if image is not selected!!
    else if selectedImageImageView.image == image
    {
        self.hideActivityIndicator()
        myAlert(title: "Error", msg: "Make sure you choose an image!")

    }else{
        
        let imageToUpload = self.selectedImageImageView.image!
        
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:
            {
                (multipartFormData) in
                
            multipartFormData.append(imageToUpload.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)!, withName: "image", fileName: self.generateBoundaryString(), mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                for (key, value) in params
                {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
                }
        }, to:url,headers:nil)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload,_,_ ):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    //Print progress
                    self.showActivityIndicator()
                })
                upload.responseJSON
                    { response in
                        //print response.result
                        if let result = response.result.value {
                            
                            //Calling response from API
                            let message = (result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "message") as! String
                            let status = (result as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! String
                            
                            //Case Success
                            if status == "1" {
                                
                                self.hideActivityIndicator()
                                print("Your Results are ====> ",result)
                                self.myAlert(title: "Data Upload", msg: message)
                                
                                
                                self.selectedImageImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "timerred")
                                self.textName.text = ""
                                self.textEmail.text = ""
                            } else if status == "2" {
                                
                           print("Email aready registered")
                                self.hideActivityIndicator()
                            }else{
                                self.hideActivityIndicator()
                                self.myAlert(title: "Error Uploading", msg: message)
                            }
                        }
                        
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

and her is the PHP code:

```
<?php
    
    include 'include/connect.php';
    
    //Get Param Data
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];

    
    $xName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $name);
    $xEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);
    $xPhone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $phone);
    
    //Results Array
    $result = array();
    
    //Image setup
    $uploads_dir = 'img';
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $image_name = basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $supported_image = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png');
    
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
    
    

    if(empty($xName) || empty($xAge)|| empty($xPhone) || empty($image_name))
    {
        
        // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
        $result["message"] = "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        $result["status"] = "0";
        $result["post"] = $_POST;
        $result["files"] = $_FILES;


    }
    
    if (! in_array($ext, $supported_image)) 
    {
            
        // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
        $result["message"] = "Sorry, Image extension is not Allowed!";
        $result["status"] = "0";
        $result["post"] = $_POST;
        $result["files"] = $_FILES;
            
    } 
    
     $check_email = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Email FROM Users where email = '$email' ");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check_email)){
    
    echo('Email Already exists');
    
    // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
            $result["message"] = "Data has been uploaded successfully.";
            $result["status"] = "2";
            $result["post"] = $_POST;
            $result["files"] = $_FILES;
    
} else {
         
         $query ="INSERT INTO Users (name, email, phone, image) VALUES ('$xName', '$xEmail','$xPhone', '$image_name')";
        
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
            
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"$uploads_dir/$image_name");
            
            // Send some dummy result back to the iOS app
            $result["message"] = "Data has been uploaded successfully.";
            $result["status"] = "1";
            $result["post"] = $_POST;
            $result["files"] = $_FILES;
                
        }      
     }

    echo json_encode($result);
        
?>
```

I do not know what is missing, I hope to find the answer.
Thanks

Comment: is this a server or a client issue, I find it hard to understand from your question? Is the server correctly finding and sending a response when a duplicate email exists?

Comment: it is a server using MySql and PHP and yes, it is sending and responding and it will store the new email and other info, but when ever the email registered before it will not store it but it will not send any response back to swift. i hope you got the idea @JoakimDanielson

Comment: So this is a php and not a swift issue then

Comment: It is a Swift code an php, but as i said i do not know where is the problem